# Detect scrolled to top of div with overflow: scroll in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm creating a messaging feature. The conversation occupies only 100vh height minus the header - so, I have to make its overflow set to scroll. How do I detect if the user scrolls to the topmost part of the conversation? I will fetch older messages once the user scrolls to the top.

I did some research but none of them are working. I think they're only applicable for a scrollable page.

The code snippet below is similar to what I am seeing over the web. However, the scroll never gets triggered.

```js
const top_ref = React.useRef < HTMLDivElement > null;

const trackScrolling = () => {
  console.log("scrolling");
};

React.useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("scroll", trackScrolling);

  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("scroll", trackScrolling);
  };
});
```

Comment: use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver for this. Check if an element intersects and if yes -> fetch more messages.

Comment: I'll take a look at the Intersection Observer. Thanks!

Comment: Intersection Observer works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [cloned](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4733161/cloned), Intersection Observer does the job.